# What is the most likely standard deviation for a sample size of 1?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to intelligently guess what a distribution might look like based only on a single sample drawn from that distribution. I've got a sample mean, but obviously no sample standard deviation.

It seems, however, that even if I can't describe the sample standard deviation for my data, there should be a way to describe a most likely standard deviation. I can consider that, for my mean, if the population has any standard deviation, the distribution most likely to generate my sample point is one with a mean equal to that sample point. I'm stumped, though, on trying to reason through how to do the same for standard deviation. If I assume my mean is equal to the sample mean, then the distribution most likely to generate my sample point is one with a standard deviation of 0, but that standard deviation has zero chance of generating my sample point for any other mean. As my sample mean gets progressively further away from the true mean, I can similarly describe some optimal standard deviation for which the chance of generating my sample point is maximized, which increases as the mean error increases. I'm not sure, however, how or if I can combine these two.

Intuitively it seems like there's some reasonable guess for sample standard deviation that's proportional to my sample point, but I can't quite get there. I feel like there should be some way to integrate over the entire range for both sample distribution and mean and come up with some centroid that describes the most likely standard deviation, but my math skills aren't up to snuff for actually computing that. I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, and they didn't teach us this stuff in college.

Is this possible to do? Has this been shown, in a general sense?

Comment: I don't share this intuition. Since any constant can be added or subtracted from a distribution without changing its standard deviation, there's no expected relationship between the mean and the standard deviation (in particular, no reason to suspect that they're proportional).

Comment: "I'm trying to intelligently guess what a distribution might look like based only on a single sample " ? This does not sound like an intelligent thing to do :) -- sorry, could not resist it.

Comment: If you are restricting to considering a certain family of distributions, this may be within the realm of feasibility (e.g., you know your data comes from a Poisson distribution, where all the distributions' variances equal their means). But in complete generality, this is not possible.

Comment: @GregMartin My assumption was based on the idea that my sample point s1 comes from a distribution described by some mu + sigma*epsilon, where epsilon is an unknown unit distribution describing the shape of the population. I can't distinguish between contribution from mean and deviation from the mean, but there is a positive correlation between the absolute value of my sample mean and the population standard deviation (sigma).

Comment: Then that's information you need to add (with definitions of the notation) to the post itself.

Comment: If your sample comes from a measurement with a known precision, then we can consider your estimate of the mean to be distributed accordingly, and then you could pick the standard deviation that maximizes the likelihood of the observation assuming the mean follows that distribution. This probably boils down to just using the measurement's $\sigma$ as your guess for the population's.

Comment: If you assumed a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for the single observation $X$, then I suspect that the maximum likelihood estimators of the parameters are $\hat \mu = X$ and $\hat \sigma = 0$, which is not particularly attractive.  It is possible to produce a conservative confidence interval for $\mu$ from a single observation, though I am not sure the same can be said for for $\sigma$: if it were possible then I suspect it might stretch down to $0$.

Comment: @ckersch Why don't you just specify your actual physical setup? It may happen that it, indeed, calls for a one-parametric family of distributions and then the maximal likelihood technique will apply. However if there are more parameters, you just may have to declare that the mission is impossible and stop at that.

Comment: @fedja My main goal is to handle the multi-parameter case. I'm trying to normalize my data as best I can based on the first point generated by an optimization process. The single-point limitation is a preexisting limitation that I'm trying to work around. I'd prefer to change it, since that will make everything we do much more accurate, but I'm looking for a backstop solution in case I can't convince the relevant decision makers that doing so is necessary...

Answer (score 2):

You have one data point and want to estimate two numbers. I don't think so.

If you have *a priori* information that some value $V > 1$ is extremely unlikely (say, $V=100$) you could assume a value for the probability of a result greater than $V$ and fit a normal  distribution.

If negative values are impossible, you could fit a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) instead.

If you do that, be sure to make your assumptions clear.

Comment: I don't unfortunately. The only thing I can really say is that my data is usually the output of physics simulations, which are generally positive. This is for application in a fairly generic piece of software I'm working on that can handle data coming from a wide range of applications.

I feel like I should be able to say, though, that an extremely high standard deviation is less likely given a low value, since I'd have a low chance of generating that value given that std. dev. Similarly, a high value is more likely given a high std dev. I'm not sure how to quantify that, though.

Comment: @ckersch "High" and "low" make little sense without the units and context. 1 meter is a long distance if you're trying to blow out a candle. 1 inch would be better. 1 meter is a short distance if you're trying to throw a football. I think the software you imagine may be too general to be useful. You might have to consider giving your user some tuning knobs.